# How to troubleshoot a MySQL / MariaDB error

Tags: centos, mysql, centos7, mariadb

I've imported two Wordpress databases to a system (CentOS7), and I did not have any problems.

When I try to import an .sql file (obtained with mysqldump command) for a vBulleting forum (the newest version) I get something like this:

```
ERROR 2006 (HY000) at line 1501: MySQL server has gone away
```

I added max_allowed_packet=16M to /etc/my.cnf and restared the MariaDB, but this did not make any difference. I was also looking at the entries in /var/log/mariadb/mariadb.log, but there is no info there about this problem.

How would I figure out what may be going on and fix it?

Thanks.

Comment: max_allowed_packet was the actual issue, I added this correctly and it worked.